# Total Differential Exercise: Production Function in Growth Rates.

Tags: functions, derivatives, economics, differential, total-variation

I'm struggling to understand how Khan & Reinhart (1990) go from the next production function.

$$y=A f(K,L,Z)$$

Where $y$ is the production of the economy, $A$ is a variable which contains the technological change, $K$ is the capital stock of the economy, $L$ is the labor (work) of the economy, $Z$ is a vector of variables containing usual covariates.

Into the following result as an expression of growth-rates.

$$\frac{dy}{y} = \left[A \frac{\partial y}{\partial K}\right] \frac{dK}{y} + \left[A \frac{\partial y}{\partial L}  \frac{L}{y} \right]\frac{dL}{L} + \left[A \frac{\partial y}{\partial Z}\frac{Z}{y}\right]\frac{dZ}{Z} + \frac{dA}{A}$$

The information is that $y,K,L,Z$ are variables (redundant I know but I want to make it clear), however, in the article, they mention $A$ as assumed to grow an exogenous rate (I assume that $A$ is also taken as a variable in the first equation). They don't make clear anymore transformations, simply "growth terms".

The last expression is mentioned by the authors to be "growth terms" of $y=Af(K,L,Z)$. but I lost it that way. Usually for expressing growth rates I simply use logarithms and differentiate over time. but this approach is not clear to me.

My intuition is that $y$ was calculated with the total differential of the form of
$$dy=\frac{\partial y}{\partial K}dK + \frac{\partial y}{\partial L}dL + \frac{\partial y}{\partial A}dA$$

and then it was divided by $y$. However, I never saw the total differentials while I was studying, so I don't know if $A$ is multiplying $f$ and we may need to proceed with the product rule of the derivatives? or what is actually the process to get the result of $dy/y$ as they get.

Reference:
Khan, M. S. & Reinhart, C. M. (1990) Private investment and economic growth in developing countries World Development, Volume 18, Issue 1, January 1990, Pages 19-27, DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/0305-750X(90)90100-C

Comment: Here $A$ is a constant. It does not depend on $K,L$ or $Z$. So $\frac{\partial y}{\partial K}=A\cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial K}$

Comment: @callculus Thank you, then half of the problem is solved. Can you please elaborate further? I'm still not getting the $\frac{L}{y}$ for the second term, also $\frac{Z}{y}$, where are they coming from the $L$ and $Z$ of the second and third term. also why it out turns to exist $dA/A$ if it is a constant?

Comment: I don´t know why it is written in this way. We can cancel L and have what we both expect. And $$\frac{\partial y}{\partial A}\cdot \frac{dA}{y}$$ is just $$f\cdot \frac{dA}{A\cdot f}= \frac{dA}{A}$$. It seems they have overcomplicated the calculation.

Comment: Thank you!!! it really helped me me to understand it this

Comment: You´re welcome, John.